# Prismic, Nuxt3, Typescript - how to retrieve content type relationship links typed (fetchLinks or graphQuery)

Tags: typescript, nuxt3, prismic

How can i retrieve typed documents / models for relationships when querying data?

```
const { data: document } = await useAsyncData('[product-uids]', () =>
  client.getByUID('product', route.params.product_id as string, {
    fetchLinks: [
      'product_symbols.symbols',
      
    ],
  })
);
```

The data is received but the (related) types are not resolved. When iterating the document: **document.data?.symbols?.data?.symbols?.data** typescript dont know about the fetched links and data is unknown. Right now instead of data (what is actually there) typescript think **link_type** is the property.

Is there a way of resolving the nested types without going crazy and doing all kinda hacks?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, i go over prismic documentation, and here is the example I found

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ $prismic, params, error }) {
    const document = await $prismic.api.getByUID('page', params.uid)

    if (document) {
      return { document }
    } else {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
    }
  }
}
```

In the following example, you will see that prismic doesn't provide a type when it's dependent on fetching data because the compiler doesn't really know what he will receive, **because you can send any data schema over the same endpoint when you build the backend**

The only solution that you can do as a developer when you build a front-end or backend with any technology and stack that you want is to create a shared folder with shared types to let the both `front` and `back` to import the shared types from there

You should create an interface to receive and display the data. This is the safest way to ensure consistency and security.

```
const getAcademic = async (): Promise<IAcademic> => {
  return (await backendInstance.get("/academic/:id")).data;
};

const useGetAcademic = (auth?: string) => {
  return useQuery<IAcademic, Error>(["academic"], getAcademic);
};
```

try to make one request and you will receive a big object with all the data, then take this object to this website and he will build for you an interface
https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript

Comment: That is really time consuming. Then the auto typescript generation (from prismic and slice maschine) is kinda obsolete. There must be a easier way.

Comment: @JeppePepp No, it's really what we do, it's doesn't matter which tool you use like `React Query` it needs to know what the variable will receive, the data coming from the backend to the frontend doesn't know exactly what they will receive, you must till the variable or the function that she will return something, and this something is type or interface

Comment: But there is a big difference between React Query (or w/e) and in this case Prismic. Prismic auto generates typed models for you. All the document models are already there. The issue is loading related content relationships and getting the typed model to understand this.
I rather then just use normal js and opt out of typescript because the data is there. I would really need to see a really good example of where u argue about that to prove me that its the way to go.